# Deployment with Servicestack.Text 4.0.18 in WCF

Tags: asp.net, wcf, .net-assembly, servicestack-text

![enter image description here][1]I've build a WCF Class library project in which I've used ServiceStack.Text assembly version 4.0.18 .

My whole soultions is build against .NET 4.0.

The project works fine when debugging, using ASP.NET self-hosting. But I've made another WCF Service Application which includes this class library and I want to deploy the WCF application on IIS, I've deployed on IIS but I get the following error :

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'AdCarWebService' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

Source Error:

```
Line 57:                 <add assembly="System.EnterpriseServices, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
Line 58:                 <add assembly="System.Web.Mobile, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
Line 59:                 <add assembly="*"/>
Line 60:                 <add assembly="System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL"/>
Line 61:                 <add assembly="System.IdentityModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL"/>
```

Comment: seems like the WCF class library is a different .NET version than ServiceStack?

Comment: that makes sense. but I searched to find out the .NET version of the ServiceStack.Text 4.0.18, but nothing so far :(

Comment: There is no such version of .NET as 4.0.18. I think this is the assembly version itself.

Comment: Yes, this is the assembly version and it's been released about 10-12 days ago. anyway I'm moving either to an older assembly or to Json.NET